# asp:image or img

Tags: asp.net, html, performance

Does `asp:Image` tag perform faster than normal HTML `img` tag?

I have 20 images to show on a web page (tiny images) and I have no idea which one to use.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### On server-side

HTML elements in usual use (without setting `runat="server"` on them) are **always faster** compared to server-side counterparts, because they don't execute any additional server-side logic or consume other resources. They also don't add anything to page's view state.

### On client-side

Simple server-side controls (those that translate to a single HTML element) are no different to normal HTML elements. But complex server-side controls (like calendar) are complex in terms of HTML element quantity thus require some additional browser resources. But making the same thing/functionality with usual HTML would create more or less similar results. So we can assume on the client-side speed is **the same**.

### Verdict

Use server side controls only when you need to add some server-side processing to it. If not, rather use *plain-old-HTML-controls*. They will be processed faster on the server, will not add anything to view state and will work with the same speed on the client as their server-side counterparts.

This is true for any HTML element that has a server-side equivalent (like `img` that has `asp:Image` on the server side). When there's no client-side equivalent (like calendar) you have to of course use server side controls or use some client-side library that provides such functionality (jQuery has a date picker for instance). But you have to know Asp.net processing quite well to combine the two effectively.

Answer (score 2):

use asp:image only if you have to manipulate it on the server side (dynamically setting the title, source, visible, etc).

since asp:image is "running" at the server side, it consumes a bit of memory and cpu usage.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `<img />` tag if you don't need to interact with it programmatically. That's less overhead (although the overhead of using asp:Image is minor).

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no performance difference at all when it comes to loading the images. The `asp:Image` control produces an `img` tag, so the result that arrives to the browser is more or less identical.

The `asp:Image` control is convenient if you want to control it's attributes from the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

The img tag will be faster for sure because no server side processing and not have ViewState (which can be disabled still).

Typically if you don't need to set properties dynamically don't use `<asp:Image ... />`

Remember you can always do something like:

```
<img src='<%= MyPathMethodInCodeBehind("some value") %>' 
     alt='<%= MyClass.SomeMethod(someParam) %>'              />
```

However, the difference is really small and would argue it's not notable, yes, even for 20 images.